# Getting rounded corners on an image

Tags: maui

I'm on another .Net Maui project and am trying to get things to look like I want them.  I want the picture to show as a rectangle with nice rounded corners.  This is being tested / debugged in iOS; specifically the simulator.

I created a new page to show what I'm experiencing.

Attempt #1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="TestApp.TestPage"
         Title="Test">

<Grid BackgroundColor="LightGray">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <VerticalStackLayout Margin="20,20">
                <Border Stroke="Black" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10" StrokeThickness="2" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="75">
                    <Image Source="hamburger.jpg"  HeightRequest="75" WidthRequest="80" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
                </Border>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    
    
</Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

And that gives the result of this:

[image: attempt 1]

The image doesn't have its corners clipped.

I then tried to create an imageButton because they will be touching the selection anyway and there will be text with it.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="TestApp.TestPage"
         Title="Test">

<Grid BackgroundColor="LightGray">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Stroke="Black" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10" StrokeThickness="4" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" Margin="10,10,10">
    <HorizontalStackLayout HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="225" Spacing="15"  VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" >
        <ImageButton Source="hamburger.jpg" Margin="8" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="80" CornerRadius="10" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"></ImageButton>
        <Label FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Transparent">burger</Label>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Border>

</Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

The result I got from that code is this:

[image: Attempt 2]

The imageButton has nice, rounded corners, but the image doesn't.  I've played with corner radius in the imageButton but it makes things look odd. It also looks like it's rounding the left and right side vs. the corners.  The button itself looks exactly the way I want it.  The image not so much.

What I am looking for is something like this:

[image: what I want]

FreakyAli's code provided this:

[image]

Trevor's concept:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should be doing now is adding a border to the actual image control as well as the whole thing, whatever you need to add a border to needs to be the child of this control so your XAML would look something like below:

```
         <Border Stroke="Black"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10"
            StrokeThickness="4"
            BackgroundColor="LightGreen">
        <Grid ColumnSpacing="10" ColumnDefinitions="3*,7*">
            <Border Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="5"
                    Stroke="Transparent"
                    StrokeThickness="0"
                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10" >
                <Image Source="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/burger-tomateoes-lettuce-pickles-on-600nw-2309539129.jpg"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </Border>
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   FontSize="20"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   Text="Burger"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

[image]

Another suggestion I would give you is not to use Height and Width requests everywhere since this won't scale as per devices, Checkout [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid?view=net-maui-8.0) and start using it based on your requirements.

Let me know if there are any queries

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't round the corners at all.  I took off the height and width to see this better.  Look at the bottom of the original question for the image I got. Thanks!

Comment: I was not aware that you needed a full-fledged solution, I thought you just needed a nudge in the right direction anyway I am updating my code have a look I guess

Comment: The problem I'm having is I've taken code from last year on a project that I did which has this and it works in that project.  From what I can tell, there was something upgraded at some point which is not working right (Frames seem to be deprecated).  I've run through every iteration I can see, but nothing seems to clip the image into the border)

Comment: Just to be clear this is supposed to be in a listview/collectionview?

Comment: Yes, I'm pulling from a db to display the information in a with an image and some text on the page.  Once I get this working, I'll pull it into a collectionview.

Comment: Adding updated code in a min

Comment: Thats exactly what I am looking for and that's a lot more work than I had to do previously! Thanks a ton, FreakyAli.

Comment: If you are a VS windows user checkout XAML Styler it will help you keep your XAML streamlined, If you are gonna be using MAUI extensively checkout my Github, it has a bunch of cool stuff you might find useful, also checkout my other socials i have tons of cool stuff for MAUI

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Xamarin.Forms approach using `Image.Clip` with `EllipseGeometry` can still be used to round the corners of an image. It does not appear to play nicely with `Image.BackgroundColor` (at least on Android). Here is an example:

```xml
<Image
    Source="dotnet_bot.png"
    MaximumHeightRequest="80"
    MaximumWidthRequest="80">
    <Image.Clip>
        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="40" RadiusY="40" Center="40,40" />
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

Comment: That still doesn't quite work, it's rounding the left and right side.  I'll add a picture of it above.